# Netlogo, how to capture values of variables of turtles and add each turtles value, map them, and reduce them to a single #

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to write a procedure where a turtle of a certain breed asks turtles of the same breed, within a certain distance, the value of a certain variable. The asking turtle will then capture the values add them to it's own, map + them and then reduce + to a single number. Here's the code

```
 ask Teams
  [ if AsgnE = "E 1"
    [
      ask Teams with [ distance myself < 25]
      [
         ; assuming that there are no more then 2 teams within distance
        let Val1 []
        let Val2 []
        let Val3 []
        set Val1 Value 
        set Val2 Value 
        set Val3 [Value] of self
        let Val4 (map + Val1 Val2 Val3) 
        set Val4 (reduce + Val4)
      set Storys1 [Stories] of Epic 0
     if Storys1 > 0 [ set TotValue1 Val4 ]
     ]
   ]
 ]
```

The values of each Team continuously update as long as the go button is pressed. The issue is that the resulting number never matches the aggregate of all the values. As the number updates they never match the totals of the separate Teams. Sometimes the number drops to a lower number (I'm assuming it's representing a single teams value) before jumping back to a higher number.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks

Rudy

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's a synchronicity problem. The `ask` will iterate (in random order) through all the turtles. Let's say it starts with turtle 1 - so turtle 1 updates its value to be the sum of its old value and all the values of the nearby turtles. Then the ask moves on to turtle 2, and turtle 2 happens to be nearby to turtle 1. That means turtle 2 adds all the numbers again, with turtle 1 having its adjusted value. With just these two turtles, the value for turtle 2 gets added in twice because turtle 1 also has it hidden in its new value.

If this is not the behaviour you want, the easiest thing to do is to have an extra variable called something like next-value. Calculate next-value for each turtle as the appropriate sum. Then, in a new `ask`, get each turtle to `set value next-value` to update them all at the same time.

Also, your map and reduce seems unnecessarily complicated. If what you are trying to achieve is to add the value of a variable over a bunch of turtles, then you can simply do a `sum` of the variable after constructing the relevant turtle agentset. But it may be that you simplified for the purposes of the question, in which case just ignore this!

**UPDATE ---- added complete model example**

```
turtles-own
[ team
  myval
  nextval
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set team one-of ["A" "B"]
    set myval 1
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles
  [ let myteam turtles with [team = [team] of myself]
    set nextval sum [myval] of myteam
  ]
  type "total before: " print sum [myval] of turtles
  ask turtles
  [ set myval nextval
  ]
  type "total after: " print sum [myval] of turtles
end
```

Comment: Thanks JenB for responding so quickly. How would I calculate a next value for each turtle, how would I isolate the inputs from each turtle to calculate their values?

Comment: see the example i added - you isolate by using a different variable to store the calculation results and don't move it back into the main variable until all the calculations are done

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond sooner, I was traveling. I will try the code tomorrow.

Comment: Hi JenB, the code works if I use "1" for the value of the myval variable but my code requires the value of myval (or in my case the variable "Value" in place of "myval") to be a continuous input from another Netlogo model (connected via Levelspace). When I do this I get the Runtime Error: "LPUT expected input to be a list but got the number 0 instead." I know the Levelspace connected model is feeding information but for some reason, utilizing your code, the information isn't being recognized. Any thoughts or solutions? Thanks

Comment: I haven't worked with levelspace at all sorry. But perhaps you could try printing out the information coming from levelspace to be sure it's in the format you think. This sounds like a separate question to me, and it would be good to see the code that's using the levelspace information (and generating the error)